# User-Agent in mvc 5 application

Tags: c#, browser, asp.net-mvc-5, user-agent

I Have a MVC 5 application whose back-end is web API. For each request to my server I need to provide user-agent which I can get in controller action method like `var UserAgent = Request.UserAgent.ToString();` and pass subsequently in other class like (**Controller => Service => HttpRequester => XXXHttpClient**) and finally use in actual request in **XXXHttpClient** class but I think there could be a better way to achieve the same. I tried to google it but didn't find anything relevant so can anyone guide me what would be the best practice If I want to get user-agent directly in XXXHttpClient class instead of passing subsequently.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Little bit of a broad question with a lot of possible answers.

Passing the data through all the layers is usually not a good thing.

What I would do is make an MVC action filter that grabs the user agent and sets it to an object. The object class could be like this:

```
public class RequestContext
{
    public string UserAgent { get; set; }
}
```

Use your dependency injection framework to inject this once-per-request. Then the action filter and the layer that depends on the data would use the same instance, allowing you to get the data to any layer that needs it.

Another option which uses a static property:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent
```

Greater performance, easier to read, but lower testability :)

Comment: once-per-request means on Action Method level ?

Comment: Yes, typically DI frameworks offer "transient" scope that means an instance is created for every object that requires it, "singleton" scope that means a single instance is shared by all objects that request it, and a "request" scope that means any objects that are created as part of a single HTTP request, get the same instance. In Ninject, this is `InRequestScope()`.

Comment: Install [Ninject.MVC5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.MVC5/) from NuGet (if using MVC5). It will generate a file where you can register your dependencies. You would use something like `kernel.Bind<RequestContext>().ToSelf().InRequestScope();`. You can find the different scopes documented here: https://github.com/ninject/Ninject/wiki/Object-Scopes

Comment: Can I use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent.ToString(); in XXXHttpClient class ?

Comment: maximun characters for `HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent` ?